# Microsoft JScript runtime error 'document is undefined' in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm developing a website which access the camera and takes the photo and upload it to server using PHP while going through this I got an error saying

```
Error: 'document' is undefined
Code: 800A1391
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

But this works good on mac and the problem arises in windows

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });

    $('#accesscamera').on('click', function() {
        Webcam.reset();
        Webcam.on('error', function() {
            $('#photoModal').modal('hide');
            swal({
                title: 'Warning',
                text: 'Please give permission to access your webcam',
                icon: 'warning'
            });
        });
        Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
    });

    $('#takephoto').on('click', take_snapshot);

    $('#close').on('click', function(){
        console.log('close');
        Webcam.reset();
    });

    $('#retakephoto').on('click', function() {
        $('#my_camera').addClass('d-block');
        $('#my_camera').removeClass('d-none');

        $('#results').addClass('d-none');

        $('#takephoto').addClass('d-block');
        $('#takephoto').removeClass('d-none');

        $('#retakephoto').addClass('d-none');
        $('#retakephoto').removeClass('d-block');

        $('#uploadphoto').addClass('d-none');
        $('#uploadphoto').removeClass('d-block');
    });

    $('#photoForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'photoUpload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 'success') {
                    Webcam.reset();

                    $('#my_camera').addClass('d-block');
                    $('#my_camera').removeClass('d-none');

                    $('#results').addClass('d-none');

                    $('#takephoto').addClass('d-block');
                    $('#takephoto').removeClass('d-none');

                    $('#retakephoto').addClass('d-none');
                    $('#retakephoto').removeClass('d-block');

                    $('#uploadphoto').addClass('d-none');
                    $('#uploadphoto').removeClass('d-block');

                    $('#photoModal').modal('hide');

                    swal({
                        title: 'Success',
                        text: 'Photo uploaded successfully',
                        icon: 'success',
                        buttons: false,
                        closeOnClickOutside: false,
                        closeOnEsc: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    })
                }
                else {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: 'Something went wrong',
                        icon: 'error'
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
})

function take_snapshot()
{
    //take snapshot and get image data
    Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
        //display result image
        $('#results').html('<img src="' + data_uri + '" class="d-block mx-auto rounded"/>');

        var raw_image_data = data_uri.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\;base64\,/, '');
        $('#photoStore').val(raw_image_data);
    });

    $('#my_camera').removeClass('d-block');
    $('#my_camera').addClass('d-none');

    $('#results').removeClass('d-none');

    $('#takephoto').removeClass('d-block');
    $('#takephoto').addClass('d-none');

    $('#retakephoto').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#retakephoto').addClass('d-block');

    $('#uploadphoto').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#uploadphoto').addClass('d-block');
}
```

My php file is

```
<div>
  <form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <input id="name" name="name" value="">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="photoModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Capture Photo</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <div id="my_camera" class="d-block mx-auto rounded overflow-hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="results" class="d-none"></div>
                    <form method="post" id="photoForm">
                        <input type="hidden" id="photoStore" name="photoStore" value="">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mx-auto text-white" id="takephoto">Capture Photo</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mx-auto text-white d-none" id="retakephoto">Retake</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mx-auto text-white d-none" id="uploadphoto" form="photoForm">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
        
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="./plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./plugin/webcamjs/webcam.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

when I click the button submit the error occurs the photo upload all works fine but while submitting the 1st form it arises an error.

Is there any solution to solve this issue without `npm` at max.

Comment: On Windows, which specific browser and version is giving you this error?

Comment: @ChrisHaas brave browser

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have tried in all browsers that I have chrome, firefox and brave but still the same occurs

Comment: And that error isn’t in a browser console, it is something that’s pops up, right?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yeah you're right!

Comment: This has the feeling of being a bug more related to the web cam's software, either the OS's or possibly the driver. Have you tried different webcams? I'm also curious if `webcamjs/webcam.min.js` is causing this. Unfortunately, I think you will need to debug this line-by-line to determine where this is ultimately coming from.